# Delete chat - XMPP framework - Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmpp, chat, xmppframework

I am working in a chat application using **XMPP framework**, and I am using a local database also ie. **sqlite**. Now, I want to add a feature to **delete the chat**. Chat can be one to one chat or group chat.

I want to delete the chat for particular user or group.

I tried many options from **stackoverflow** but did not find any suitable answer. Please help if anybody has any idea about it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The deleting chat is dependent on how is your server side setup

In our case server maintains 2 copies of messages for sender and receiver.

We use IQ stanza to delete chat, satanza is as follows

**SENDER:**

```
<iq type="set" id="B4032092-E3EE-4AA3-90A2-4C38A9807407"><query xmlns="urn:xmpp:mam:1"><x xmlns="jabber:x:data" type="submit"><field var="FORM_TYPE" type="hidden"><value>urn:xmpp:mam:1</value></field><field var="start"><value>2019-04-17T12:20:42Z</value></field></x><set xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/rsm"><max>10</max></set></query></iq>
```

**ACK FROM SERVER:**

```
<iq type="set" id="9f22eb11-c0e8-410f-bb8c-54e95a4f2f80=7FE2EFBD-E92A-41BF-B7C7-FC7749728F3A"><query xmlns="urn:xmpp:mam:2" queryId="9f22eb11-c0e8-410f-bb8c-54e95a4f2f80=10D528E8-BA5D-498C-B54C-85DFD01DAE5A"><x xmlns="jabber:x:data" type="submit"><field var="FORM_TYPE" type="hidden"><value>urn:xmpp:mam:2</value></field><field var="end"><value>2019-04-17T12:39:22Z</value></field><field var="with"><value>9f22eb11-c0e8-410f-bb8c-54e95a4f2f80@localhost</value></field></x><set xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/rsm"><max>30</max><before/><reversed/></set></query></iq>
```

I'm sure it won't fix it directly, but it should give a hint to you.